# Listview listselector not working

Tags: android

I am creating some views in my xml file, xml file contaings list-view.
In that list-view I have list selector attribute and i defined drawable 
image for selector.

My xml file follows like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <com.naaima.vovinet.activity.VideoNativePlayer 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip" 
                    android:layout_width="800dip" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dip" 
                    android:id="@+id/video_view" 
                    android:layout_height="600dip" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dip">
                </com.naaima.vovinet.activity.VideoNativePlayer>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>  

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textView_channelno" 
                    android:layout_width="130dip"
                    android:hint="_ _ _"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1050dip" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/sample"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="25dip"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_height="80dip"/>


                </LinearLayout>



            <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout2" 
                android:layout_width="1100dip" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dip">



                <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                        <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
                            android:layout_width="730dip" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                            android:background="@drawable/progress_bar_bg"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"/>

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView_date" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progressBar"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"/>

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView_time" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_date"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="57dip" 
                            />  

                     <TextView 
                            android:id="@+id/textView_location"
                            android:text="Hyderabad" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_time" 
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_temp"
                            />

                           <TextView 
                            android:id="@+id/textView_temp"
                            android:text="35 Degrees" 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_location"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_temp"
                            />

                       <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView_temp"
                            android:src="@drawable/temp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/textView_time"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"/>

                     <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
                            android:src="@drawable/zee"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"/>


                      <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView_left"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_gray"
                            android:layout_marginTop="110dip"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"/>

                        <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_channelName"
                            android:text="M-Tunes"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="110dip"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"/>

                        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView_right"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_gray"
                            android:layout_marginTop="110dip"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="150dip"/>

                        <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
                            android:layout_width="690dip"
                            android:layout_height="125dip"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="220dip"
                                            android:listSelector="@drawable/highlight_bar"/>  
                                <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView_up"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/arrow_up_gray"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"/>


                                </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </FrameLayout>`
```

Row.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >
        <TextView android:text="TextView" 
            android:id="@+id/textView_list" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And java code is like following

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Now:Harry Potter and Deathly Hellows", "Lord of the Rings:Two Towers", "Lord of the Rings:Return of King",
                    "rd of the Rings:Honneypot solo Dance"};

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.row,R.id.textView_list, values);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setSelector(R.drawable.highlight_bar);
            lv.setDivider(null);
```

If I am executing only listview with row xml code list selector working fine.
If I am pressing up and down arrows it's working fine. But I am integrating 
listview with above code it's not working and if I am pressing up and arrows 
in keyboard no use (focusing not going to listview side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling "requestFocus()" on the listView in your code after setting android:focusable="true" in the xml?  From the View [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29):

"Call this to try to give focus to a specific view or to one of its descendants. A view will not actually take focus if it is not focusable (isFocusable() returns false), or if it is focusable and it is not focusable in touch mode (isFocusableInTouchMode()) while the device is in touch mode. See also focusSearch(int), which is what you call to say that you have focus, and you want your parent to look for the next one. This is equivalent to calling requestFocus(int, Rect) with arguments FOCUS_DOWN and null."

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to Jason's above response. I recently ran into this issue and Jason's answer was spot on, except I needed to call **requestFocusFromTouch()** on my listView to make it work in response to touch obviously. requestFocus() was *not* helpful in my scenario but requestFocusFromTouch() was. Hopefully that helps someone out there.